# Use induction to prove for all $n \ge 1$, if $f(x) = ax^n$ then$ f '(x) = anx^{n-1}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

So for the base case: $n=1$
$$F'(1) = a(1)x^0 = a$$ So this checks out.

So I can assume: $f(x) = ax^k$  then $f'(x) = a\ k\ x^{k-1}$

For the induction $n = k+1$.

$f'(x) = a(k+1)\ x^{(k+1)-1}$ ....I do not know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: From the product rule, we find that

$$\frac{d}{dx} x^{n + 1} = \frac{d}{dx} x^n \cdot x = \left(\frac{d}{dx} x^n \right) x + x^n \left(\frac{d}{dx} x\right)$$

Comment: Thank you @T.Bongers, so I would get something close to: a(k+1)x^(k-1)* a(k+1)x^k. Do I then distrubte the a's?